# Creating a batch script to send an email if a file's created date isn't today

Tags: windows, email, batch-file, batch-processing

I'm new to scripting so this answer might be really easy but I haven't been able to find it using Google. Anyways, I need to create a batch script that will send a notification email if it sees that a certain file's creation date isn't the current date.

Larger picture:
I am backing up a database that is pretty small and have created a script to copy the DB over the network to a shared file. I need to make sure that the file is getting re-written every day and the best way I know how is to compare the creation date to today's date and then to fire off a "success" or "failure" email with what it finds. Below is what I have so far but not sure what else I need for it to work or even if I'm on the right path.

```
cd /
cd /Ppak Backup
dir /T:C engine.db
if !filedate! == %DATE% (C:\Users\administrator.BENCHMARK\Desktop\sendEmail.exe -f copier@benchmarkwoodworks.com -t backup@erootsohio.com -u backup -m backup successful -s smtp.office365.com:25 -xu copier@benchmarkwoodworks.com -xp xxxxxxx) else (C:\Users\administrator.BENCHMARK\Desktop\sendEmail.exe -f copier@benchmarkwoodworks.com -t backup@erootsohio.com -u backup -m backup fail -s smtp.office365.com:25 -xu copier@benchmarkwoodworks.com -xp xxxxxxx)
```

Answer (score 0):

Run `forfiles /?` and you'll see the help page for a useful command that will let you select files based on date criteria and run a command on those files.

In your specific case, you could find that file if dated today with:

```
forfiles /D 0 /P "\Ppak Backup" /M engine.db /C "path\sendEmail.exe -m succeeded ..."
```

...and if dated yesterday or older with:

```
forfiles /D -1 /P "\Ppak Backup" /M engine.db /C "path\sendEmail.exe -m failed ..."
```

For readability I didn't copy your emailer's full path and arguments. As you can see in the help page, `forfiles` also allows you to include variables such as `@fdate` and `@ftime` in the arguments to your .exe if needed.

**Edit:** Re the comment on created vs last modified, I assumed it'd be ok to use the last modified date. In fact you may *have to* use last modified if e.g. the same file is overwritten (vs deleted and replaced) every backup. To see if that's the case, compare the output of `DIR /TC engine.db` with `dir engine.db`. If you really have to go by created date, `forfiles` can't be used. Below is an alternative with `DIR /TC` instead. (The `%DATE1:~4%`part strips the weekday abbreviation from `%DATE%` and could need modifications for non-US locales.)

```
SETLOCAL
SET DATE1=%DATE%
FOR /F %%D IN ('DIR /TC "\Ppak Backup\engine.db" ^| FIND ".db"') DO IF %%D==%DATE1:~4% (path\sendEmail.exe -m succeeded ...) ELSE path\sendEmail.exe -m failed ...
```

BTW, it's a little unusual that your example uses forward slashes (`/`). Stick to Windows' and DOS' customary backslashes (`\`) even though in some cases you can get away with `/`. Guess you have a *nix background... Also, the first `CD` in your example does nothing, and in most cases there isn't a good reason to change working directory at all in cases like this, just specify a full path in the command that performs the desired action.

**Another thought:** Neither of the above variants will send any email at all if the backup happens to be missing, and this is not mentioned in the question. You may want to consider adding an `IF NOT EXIST` or so to cover that case.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had actually used forfiles before but the way I did it, it only referenced the modified date and not the created date. I will give this a shot today and see if that resolves the issue. Thank you!

Comment: I am taking a look at it today and will update asap.

Comment: @Eroots, I'm glad to hear it worked. Please also mark the answer "Accepted". [Here's why](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/317538) that's worthwhile.